# Check if at least a bit is set without jumping

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to find an efficient way to check if an integer is zero without jumping.

I have two integer variables `in` and `out`. If `in` is zero, I want `out` to be zero. If `in` is not zero, I want out to be one.

If it may help, I know that `in` will be zero or a power of two (only one set bit). I also know that the most significant and the less significant bits are never set.

I could do the obvious : `out = (in == 0 ? 0 : 1);` But that implies a jump which is costly.

I could do something like this `out = (in * 0xFFFFFFFF) >> 63;`. This implies a multiplication and shift that I would like to avoid, but I can't find a way. Maybe it's not possible.

Any other way I could do this without jump and only using bit-wise operators and arithmetic?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need this optimization? What hardware are you using?

Comment: I don't absolutely need it, but I'm designing a piece of code that will be part of the inner loop of a monte carlo simulation and I know that speed will be an issue. Also, I like to find this kind of micro-optimisations and bit-manipulations hacks. My current application will run on desktop and mobile processors.

Comment: Have you done any measurement and inspected the assembly listing?

Comment: Just stop doing premature optimizations, and your life will be happier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will differ with architecture but the code *doesn't* compile to a jump on Intel CPUs.

This code:

```
int square(int in) {
    int out = (in != 0);
    return out;
}
```

is compiled to:

```
square(int):
    xor     eax, eax
    test    edi, edi
    setne   al
    ret
```

or:

```
square, COMDAT PROC
    xor      eax, eax
    test     ecx, ecx
    setne    al
    ret      0
square ENDP
```

by msvc, clang and gcc with O2:

- msvc: https://godbolt.org/g/Mfh2Qj
- clang: https://godbolt.org/g/6p7kL1
- gcc: https://godbolt.org/g/vUM2Zv

It is only a jump with no optimization which you would never do anyway.

Comment: you can just add new compiler windows instead of using separate links for them

Answer (score 2):

I've also found the need to do this, to index a length-2 array at 0 for zero values and 1 for non-zero values.

Cast the int to bool, and then back to int. This does not jump on almost every compiler I've tried (gcc, clang, recent MSVC) except MSVC pre-2018. I recommend you check the assembly code to make sure on your platform.

```
int one_if_nonzero_else_zero(int value) { return (bool) value; }
```

EDIT: This does not satisfy your constraint "only using bit-wise operators and arithmetic" but this cast takes advantage of assembly optimization and will be very efficient.

EDIT: Your "obvious" solution `out = (in == 0 ? 0 : 1);` results in identical assembly code as solutions posted by Jerry Jeremiah and myself on gcc, clang, and msvc. No jump after optimization! I suggest you use it for clarity.

Comment: The assembly code is identical to doing the (in !-= 0) test from my answer: the same three instructions.  It's amazing how optimizers work...

Comment: Ha! `in == 0 ? 0 : 1` also compiles to those same three instructions (no jump) on msvc, clang, and gcc. Updating my answer to include this.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two integer variables `in` and `out`. If `in` is zero, I want `out` to be zero. If `in` is not zero, I want `out` to be one.

Try this:

```
int in = ...;
int out = !!in;
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/kHWR8T)

C++ has an implicit conversion defined from `int` to `bool`, so `in` as a `bool` will be `false` when `in` is 0, and will be `true` otherwise.

Then `!false` will be `true`, and `!true` will be `false`.

Then `!true` will be `false`, and `!false` will be `true`.

Then there is also an implicit conversion defined from `bool` to `int`, so `true` as an `int` will be 1, and `false` will be 0.

Thus, `out` will be 0 when `in` is 0, and will be 1 otherwise.